# How to use maven variable in scripts Liquibase?

Tags: maven, liquibase

I want to save maven information in my database like the version of my project in each run of liquibase.

I try to put my maven variable in an external properties file but it's not taken and my value is "{project.version}" in my table.

There is a way to get this information ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does that mean you put `{project.version}` in one of your liquibase changelog xml files?

Comment: Hi, i try this way yes. I try also use i an external file properties but both options failed.

Comment: I think the answer @carlspring provided should work. I haven't tested it myself though. But if you list your changelog xml files in your `pom.xml` file as a `<resource>` then maven should take care of replacing this info...

Comment: @Jens: It does. And the format is actually `${project.version}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out what [Maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) is.

When you define `<resource/>`-s in your `pom.xml`, you can turn on filtering, by doing `<filtering>true</filtering>`. This will tell Maven to replace all `${foo.bar}`-like variables in your resources.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that feature of maven. Seems like this is also done for any resource that you list in the `pom.xml`? To make this work with liquibase one would have to list all changelog xml files in the `pom.xml` - which you normally would not have to.

Comment: @jens: Just add a `<resource/>` pointing to the directory with your changelogs and add an `<includes/>` with a pattern... Why would you have to list them one by one? :)

Comment: Oh, even better. Thanks for that advice! :)

Comment: @Marie: If this solves your problem, please accept my answer.